# Import csv as List of List of Integers

Tags: python, list, csv

I have the following CSV file

```
12,29,63,44
54,43,65,34
```

I'm trying to import it as a list of list such that each index is an integer. Here's what I have so far.

```
import csv
filename = 'file.csv'
with open(filename, 'rU') as p:
        #reads csv into a list of lists
        my_list = list(list(rec) for rec in csv.reader(p, delimiter=',')) 

print my_list
>>> [['12','29','63','44'],['54','43','65','34']]
```

As you can see this produces a list of list of strings, not integers. How do I import the CSV file as a list of list of integers? like this

```
 >>> [[12,29,63,44],[54,43,65,34]]
```

Comment: Use a comprehension or `map`. Seems like you're already aware of comprehensions and generator expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) to int:

```
 my_list = [list(map(int,rec)) for rec in csv.reader(p, delimiter=',')]

 [[12, 29, 63, 44], [54, 43, 65, 34]]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
my_list = [[int(x) for x in rec] for rec in csv.reader(p, delimiter=',')]
```